# Generating a new dataframe from existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column D from existing A, B, C column.

- first value in Col D is A1
- second value in Col D is B2
- third value in Col D is C3
- fourth value in Col D is A4
- fifth value in Col D is B5
- sixth value in Col D is C6

following this pattern, the rest of the values in Col D is iteration of this pattern. Please reference the graph.

Any code ideas?

Click the link to see the picture

[image]

Comment: Is it 3 columns? Or a dynamic number?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (in a couple of steps for better clarity):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(0, 10), "b": range(10, 20), "c": range(20, 30)})

df["inx"] = range(len(df))
df["d"] = np.where(df.inx % 3 == 0, df["a"], 
         np.where(df.inx % 3 == 1, df["b"], df["c"]))
df = df.drop("inx", axis="columns")
```

Result:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  0  10  20   0
1  1  11  21  11
2  2  12  22  22
3  3  13  23   3
4  4  14  24  14
5  5  15  25  25
6  6  16  26   6
7  7  17  27  17
8  8  18  28  28
9  9  19  29   9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use, [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to create a dataframe having the columns `A`, `B`, `C` with the values in the columns are filled accordingly by consecutively iterating through the columns and selecting the next value from that column as per the conditions then use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to agg the dataframe by droping the `NaN` values:

```
d = pd.concat([df[col].iloc[i::df.columns.size] for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)], axis=1)
df['D'] = d.agg(lambda s: s.dropna().iloc[0], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
    A   B   C   D
0  A1  B1  C1  A1
1  A2  B2  C2  B2
2  A3  B3  C3  C3
3  A4  B4  C4  A4
4  A5  B5  C5  B5
5  A6  B6  C6  C6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create input dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[*'123456'], columns=[*'ABC'])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.name+x.index)
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A2  B2  C2
3  A3  B3  C3
4  A4  B4  C4
5  A5  B5  C5
6  A6  B6  C6
```

Use `cumsum` with `lookup`:

```
s = ((df['A'].notna().cumsum()-1) % df.shape[1])
df['d'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.columns[s])
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   d
1  A1  B1  C1  A1
2  A2  B2  C2  B2
3  A3  B3  C3  C3
4  A4  B4  C4  A4
5  A5  B5  C5  B5
6  A6  B6  C6  C6
```